# Can I place the Ubuntu One for Windows home sync folder anywhere on C:\ during installation?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

My company does not allow us to keep personal files inside our personal folder. Something about the roaming profiles getting to large.

With Dropbox I am able to set the destination of the folder during the install. Is there anyway to tell Ubuntu One where to put the Ubuntu One folder?

I don't want to add external folders to the sync list, I just want to control where the installer creates the Ubuntu One folder.

Otherwise I can't use the service :(

Answer (score 4):

> *How to use Ubuntu one outside the profile folder, or even the c:\ drive*

This is an alternative, but I will present it with a side note saying that you might want to know what it actually does. but sure thing this is a valid alternative.

Some reading before going.

Something to consider on the road, hardlink for same volume (same drive letter), junction for different volume (different drive letter) on the same computer.

Small [**how-to**](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/) using a program supplied with Windows 7 on the command line.

There is also a nice site with a shell extension [**here**](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

This is what I did myself to make it work:

Suppose you have a folder called Safe.data on Z: drive - `z:\safe.data`

What I did was to install the LSE shell extension and then simply right-clicked the `safe.data` folder inside the `z:` drive and selected "**Pick link source**".

After that I went to the Ubuntu One folder inside my profile folder `C:\Users\username\Ubuntu One` and right-clicked inside it then selected "**drop as: Smart mirror**".

This work as far as I'm concerned.

Please note that the "**junction**" link doesn't seem to work correctly with Ubuntu One, and also note that you can't add the "**Smart mirror link folder**" directly to Ubuntu One settings to sync it directly... to say it otherwise, make sure that the 'smart mirror link' is created inside an actual 'NORMAL' folder and select the 'NORMAL' folder to be synced when setup it up in Ubuntu one options.

That's about it.

BTW, don't know that guy with the LSE thing, but I always advice considering donating if you really enjoy. Those people keep this place nice like this.

Answer (score 2):

I did a late edit of the post with doesn't seem to show up yet, explaning a little bit on how I achieved to make it work myself using LSE shell extension.

(use a folder on another physical drive and make it sync with ubuntu one.)

All in all I hope this help someone until they release an update :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we only support syncing folders inside your profile folder. We are considering solutions for this because of requests by users in your same situation.

Answer (score 0):

This default behavior is also problematic concerning "Roaming Profiles" on windows. In our working environment U1 is currently unusable because it leads to heavy user profiles (hence long connection times for users). Therefore we are also waiting for an evolution on this particular point.